# Issue with Multiple Hibernate Transaction Manager

Tags: transactions, annotations, spring-3, sessionfactory, hibernate-4.x

I am working with Spring 3.2.5.Release and Hibernate 4.2.7.Final. I am deploying my ear on Websphere 7 server. I have two application context files and each has its own sessionFactory of type

```
   <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">....</bean>


   <bean id="sessionFactory1"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">... </bean>
```

The issue is with multiple HibernateTransactionManager. I am defining two transaction managers as

```
   <bean id="transactionManager"
     class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
     <qualifier value="transactionManager"/>
   </bean>
```

and

```
   <bean id="txManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory1" />
    <qualifier value="txManager"/>
</bean>
```

In one of the context files I have mentioned this

```
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
<bean
    class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

However, during runtime of this code,

```
    loggingManager.persistLog(loadLog); // using txManager
    .....
    persistenceService.persist(dataEntity);  // using transactionManager
```

I get the below exception

```
    org.springframework.transaction.IllegalTransactionStateException: No existing transaction found for transaction marked with propagation 'mandatory'
```

Please note that the first transaction is success. I see the id generated for loadLog. I've annoted my Service layer with

```
    @Transactional(value="txManager") // with respective transaction manager
```

And my DAO layer with

```
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
```

Is there anything that could be done to enable both the transaction managers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service is using the **txManager**

```
@Transactional(value="txManager")
```

That service is calling a repository or dao, **it** must belong or runs within the service transaction too. You must do the following:

```
@Transactional(value="txManager" propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
```

Why is **Propagation.MANDATORY**? Why not **Propagation.REQUIRED**? Or just only

```
@Transactional(value="txManager")
```

Since Propagation.REQUIRED is used used by default.

BTW consider use only `@Transactional` if your @Transactional services would be working either with **txManager** or **transactionManager**

Comment: This works! I added the transaction manager qualifier to the DAO layer and it works like a charm. The Propagation.Required stops the DAO layer being called bypassing the servicing layer. It is actually a good practice.

Comment: Interesting, I always have my DAO methods with "Required", only my services for complex use cases would be "REQUIRES_NEW", normally they are "REQUIRED" too. Of course each requirement is different.